# Get database results from frontend user's form input details

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use select statement if a laravel form has been filled. I have 2 tables **"query"** and **"all"**. If a user fills a form it is saved in **query** but I also want it to select certain fields from table **all** and returns the answer.

When a user fills in a form its now saving in query.

```php
$post = new query;
$post->name = $request->input('name');
$post->description = $request->input('description');
$post->email = auth()->user()->email;
$post->save();

session()->flash('notif', "Query has been submitted succesfully");

$check = check::select('all.*')
->where('name', '=', $post->name)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you need to get result from `all` table, where 'name' is `$post->name`. If so please check this:

```
$post = new query;
$post->name = $request->input('name');
$post->description = $request->input('description');
$post->email = auth()->user()->email;
$post->save();
session()->flash('notif', "Query has been submitted succesfully");
$check = DB::table('all')
->where('name', $post->name)
->get();
```

And please dont forget to place: `use DB;` on the top of your Controller

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what is `check` here in `check::select()`. But what I got from query is you want to select specific fields from table **"all"** after inserting the data in the table **"query"**.

So you can do this to achieve what I understood.

```php
$post = new query;
$post->name        = $request->input('name');
$post->description = $request->input('description');
$post->email       = auth()->user()->email;
$post->save();

// use any of the following
$check = all::where('name', $post->name)->get();                      // SELECT *
$check = all::where('name', $post->name)->get(['field1', 'field2']);  // SELECT 'specific'

session()->flash('notif', "Query has been submitted succesfully");
```